# Load big amount of data in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have an app that downloads a XML object and save it in a `CoreData` model. The root view shows this info in a table.

I was wondering, where is the best place to do this task (`AppDelegate`? `viewDidLoad` of the root view?)

The answer seems easy for small amounts of data, but where it should be place talking about a large file? And what´s the recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to load this data in `AppDelegate`, show an `UIActivityIndicator` and load data in background, then update your RootView, when it is finished.

Comment: Thanks, but show an activity indicator where? and, I can update the RootView with a notification, but what happens if the data is downloaded so fast that is there before the RootView is init?

Comment: mmm, you will always check in RootView, if the data is downloaded or not, if downloaded, go ahead, else, show ActivityIndicator and when downloaded post a notification to RootView.

Comment: Good answer, fair enough, one last thing, how can RootView check if the data is downloaded?

Comment: Perhaps a boolean property of your AppDelegate or query to your coredata.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to load this data in viewDidLoad of the Root view. As mentioned data is not a big so there is no need to show UIActivityIndicator.

Comment: Why do you think should be better than in the App delegate?